# Wrong destination in STOMP header when talking to hornetq server

Tags: java, hornetq, stomp

I am trying to setup a C client to talk to a hornetq jms server. I am using its STOMP acceptor with libstomp on the C side.

My C client code is just [this example](http://svn.stomp.codehaus.org/browse/stomp/trunk/c/src/main.c?r=31) from the libstomp page verbatim with the passphrase and destination queue name changed (to a valid queue that can be accessed from a java client).

Here's what I get when I run it:

```
Connecting......OK
Sending connect message.OK
Reading Response.Response: CONNECTED,
OK
Sending Subscribe.OK
Sending Message.OK
Reading Response.Response: ERROR, org.hornetq.core.protocol.stomp.StompException:     Client must set destination or id head
er to a SUBSCRIBE command
        at     org.hornetq.core.protocol.stomp.StompProtocolManager.onSubscribe(StompProtocolManager.java:    339)
        at     org.hornetq.core.protocol.stomp.StompProtocolManager.handleBuffer(StompProtocolManager.java:196)
        at     org.hornetq.core.protocol.stomp.StompConnection.bufferReceived(StompConnection.java:279)
        at     org.hornetq.core.remoting.server.impl.RemotingServiceImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferRec    eived(RemotingServ
iceImpl.java:512)
        at     org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.HornetQChannelHandler.messageReceived(HornetQChannelHa    ndler.java:73)
        at     org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100)
        at     org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:372)
        at     org.jboss.netty.channel.StaticChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(StaticChannelPipeline.java:367)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.oio.OioWorker.run(OioWorker.java:100)
        at     org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
        at     org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:44)
        at     org.jboss.netty.util.VirtualExecutorService$ChildExecutorRunnable.run(VirtualExecutorServic    e.java:181)
        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at     java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
OK
Sending Disconnect.OK
Disconnecting...OK
```

In short - I get this exception from the server:

```
ERROR, org.hornetq.core.protocol.stomp.StompException: Client must set destination or id header to a SUBSCRIBE command
```

On line 92 of the example, we set the destination:

```
apr_hash_set(frame.headers, "destination", APR_HASH_KEY_STRING, "/queue/FOO.BAR");
```

Despite this, when the message gets to the server and it parses the headers, I get a map `ation -> /queue/FOO.BAR`, but it's looking for a `destination` key. I have confirmed that the client is adding the correct map entry to the headers and it is not corrupted all the way through to sending it to the network.

Any pointers as to what might be wrong?

P.S. hornetq is 2.2.9.Final, libstomp is the latest revision from svn (rev 90 - http://svn.codehaus.org/stomp/trunk/c/), and it was compiled with apr 1.4.6; all running on Win-7

Comment: A slight correction - problem happens both with the subscribe (line 82) and the sending of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.2.9 is a pretty old HornetQ release. You should retry with 2.2.14, or with the latest 2.3.beta. I just looked at the code in git for HornetQ master, the destination is being handled

See onSubscribe() at https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/hornetq-server/src/main/java/org/hornetq/core/protocol/stomp/VersionedStompFrameHandler.java#L254

FWIW, in HornetQ a dot `.` is used as divisor for destinations (your code is using a slash `/`). The STOMP protocol leaves this as an implementation dependent convention.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over which version is used - 1. this was for an intern project and 2. we started with a slightly older, though stable, version of the app that is running the embedded HornetQ. The newer versions will probably be running a newer HornetQ as well. I tried it with a `.`, but that didn't work either - same problem. Anyway - this wasn't terribly important, so I'll leave it as is, hoping an updated hornetq might fix it.